# Zero uncertainty implies eigenstate of operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, linear-algebra

Problem statement: Given a self-adjoint operator $A=A^\dagger$, if the uncertainty $(\Delta A)_\psi = 0$, then $\psi$ is an eigenstate of $A$.
The definition of $\Delta A$: $\Delta A^2 = \langle (A - \langle A\rangle)^2\rangle$.

Attempt:

All expectations are taken with respect to a test wavefunction, $\psi$. For a self-adjoint operator, one can separately prove $\Delta A^2 = \langle A^2 \rangle - \langle A \rangle ^2$. If the uncertainty is zero then we have $\langle A^2 \rangle = \langle A \rangle ^2$;
$$
\langle \psi | A^2 | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi |A|\psi \rangle^2
$$
Using self-adjointness,
$$
\langle \psi | A A | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi |A|\psi \rangle^2
$$
Now let $|\phi \rangle = A|\psi\rangle$. Then,
$$
\langle \phi| \phi \rangle = \langle \psi |\phi \rangle^2.
$$

From here I would like to show that $\psi$ is an eigenstate of $A$. Namely, that $A|\psi \rangle = a|\psi \rangle$, for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$ (since $A=A^\dagger$). Ultimately, this means that $|\phi\rangle$ should be just a real scalar multiple of $|\psi \rangle$.

How can I go about showing this rigorously? And is this the correct way forward?

Comment: If you want to prove something but can't figure out how, it's sometimes useful to assume what you're trying to prove is false and find a contradiction. In your case, try and assume $A|\psi\rangle = a |a\rangle + b |b\rangle$ or something even more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume w.l.o.g. $||\psi||=1$. Then use the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) to obtain

$$(\psi, A\,\psi)^2 \leq ||A\,\psi||^2 = (\psi,A^2\,\psi) \quad , $$

where the equality holds if and only if $\psi$ and $A\,\psi$ are linearly dependent, i.e. $A\,\psi= a\,\psi$ for some $a\in \mathbb R$. Here, $(\cdot ,\cdot)$ denotes the scalar product and $||\cdot||$ the corresponding norm.